# Need to access variable outside a function and inside another

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, im wanting to access data.names from inside the FeederBot function so i can access the names being emited from the client. But i dont know how to. I want the variable to be accessed inside feeder bot for this.nickname = data.names. Any help?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('login', function(data) {
        console.log("User connected with id:" + data.uuid + " Bot names: " + data.names);
        socket.room = data.uuid;
        socket.join(data.uuid);

        if (data.type == "server") {
            io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit("force-login", "server-booted-up");
        }
    }.bind(this));

    socket.on('pos', function(data) {
        //console.log(socket.room + " : " + data);
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('pos', data);
    });

    socket.on('cmd', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('cmd', data);
    });

    socket.on("spawn-count", function(data) {
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit("spawn-count", data);
    });

    socket.emit("force-login", "startup");

});

function FeederBot(bot_id, agent, bot_number, server) {

    this.bot_id = bot_id; //ID of bot for logging
    this.interval_id = 0; //here we will store setInterval's ID
    this.ball_id = null;
    this.server = ''; //server address will be stored here
    this.client = new AgarioClient('Bot_' + this.bot_id); //creates new client
    this.client.debug = 0;
    this.client.agent = agent;
    this.client.headers['user-agent'] = config.userAgent;
    if (facebookManager.hasAvailableToken()) {
        this.client.auth_token = facebookManager.getToken();
    }
    this.isOnFeedMission = false; this.nickname = "Exper"

    this.lastsent = {minx: 0, miny: 0, maxx: 0, maxy: 0};
    this.onboard_client(server, bot_number);
}
```

Comment: there's a lot of `data` in your code, in each socket event handler. Which one do you want?

Comment: From the login handler

Answer (score 1):

```
var outsideVar = null;

function functionOne() {
  outsideVar = 1;
}

function functionTwo() {
  console.log(outsideVar);
}

functionOne(); // set the value of your var
functionTwo(); // output in console should be 1
```

just have a look on the scope where you define your vars. js works structured in this case and you can access vars that are defined before your function is defined and on the same scope level like your function is defined

edit:
for better understanding

```
var dataStorage = null; // before you enter any { scope with socket

{
  // ...
  socket.on('login', function(data) {

    dataStorage = data; // <<- write data to the global var dataStorage

    console.log("User connected with id:" + data.uuid + " Bot names: " +        data.names);
    socket.room = data.uuid;
    socket.join(data.uuid);

    if (data.type == "server") {      
      io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit("force-login", "server-booted-up");
    }

  }.bind(this));
  // ..
}

function FeederBot(bot_id, agent, bot_number, server) {

  this.bot_id = bot_id; //ID of bot for logging
  this.interval_id = 0; //here we will store setInterval's ID
  this.ball_id = null;
  this.server = ''; //server address will be stored here
  this.client = new AgarioClient('Bot_' + this.bot_id); //creates new client
  this.client.debug = 0;
  this.client.agent = agent;  
  this.client.headers['user-agent'] = config.userAgent;
  if (facebookManager.hasAvailableToken()) {
    this.client.auth_token = facebookManager.getToken();
  }
  this.isOnFeedMission = false; 
  this.nickname = "Exper"

  // and here you can access the global var again. 
  // make sure u test for not null and the property exists
  if(!!dataStorage) {
    if(dataStorage.hasOwnProperty('names')){
      this.nickname = data.names;
    }
  }

  this.lastsent = {minx: 0, miny: 0, maxx: 0, maxy: 0};
  this.onboard_client(server, bot_number);

}
```

Comment: Inside the login handler it has data.names. That is being emited from the client im using. Inside feederbot function im wanting the this.nickname to = data.names.

Comment: have you checked you have the same focus on data.names in both functions? i think there are differences. export to a var you definde before and you can access it from outside.

Comment: I dont really understand as im not that good at javascript, my friend sent me most of the code to add on to.

Comment: global: ``var dataStorage = null;``. in your first function you simply set ``dataStorage = data;`` and in your final function you can access to dataStorage like this: ``if(!!dataStorage){this.names = dataStorage.names}``

Comment: ReferenceError: names is not defined

Comment: look at the edit. normaly this should work now for you

Comment: fixed: ``if(dataStorage.hasOwnProperty('names')){`` there was a missing closing )

Comment: Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Wait another error: Cannot read property 'Length' of undefined

Comment: looks like you try to attach an undefined object in a loop. there is no loop in your code what i can find.